# What is the proper use of threads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have a Main activity with a few methods.

- GetTopics: calls REST API and returns JSON results
- BindTopics: displays the results from GetTopics on the screen

There are a few others with similar functionality, but I'm sure I can fit the solution to these across all methods.

Question: What is the proper way to run these in separate threads?  Should both of them be in the same thread?  Should I call BindTopics once GetTopics is complete?

Either way, doesn't the UI get built prior to the async threads are completed?  If so, how do I update the UI?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load it in a progress dialog with an AsyncTask. You will need to declare the handler to update controls in the UI thread.

Example:

```
private Handler     handler         = new Handler();


final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setTitle("Getting topics..");
pd.setMessage("Please while topics are retrieved");
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        GetTopics();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        BindTopics();

        pd.dismiss();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // update UI
                // remove loading view
                // load details of topics
            }
        });
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all your questions is [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create your UI (with some sort of loading screen), then start an AsyncTask to download the data and display it.

There is a basic blog post about AsyncTasks here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html

In the AsyncTasks doInBackground method you would call GetTopics. Then in the onPostExecute method you would call BindTopics and display the data. In the onPostExecute method you can check to see if the data downloaded properly before attempting to display it.

Answer (score 0):

The main use of threads for me were when my app had to download large amount of data from ftp server. But while downloading I wanted that the user still can use my app. If I had written the download code in main thread, the user could not use the app and all buttons would not work. The main idea of thread is to divide time of CPU usage for each thread.

If you wish more then one task to be preformed simultaneously you have to use Threads.